# insert custom item variable through xml in magento admin order detail Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, blocks, sales-order

Hi I  am developing a magento extension in which I need to show a product custom attribute in the magento order detail. I want to add it through xml without 
editing/ overwriting  any core file ..
For now i have edit the following file to show custom attribute value
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml

but I know this is not the correct way. So please suggest me how can I insert it by blocks through xml.
Below is the screen-shot link 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e42y3ac8d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved but with the help of java-script function.

To add your fields on order view page we need to do :

1. Add layout in your config file:

> ```
> <adminhtml>
>   <layout>
>       <updates>
>           <customattribute>
>               <file>customattribute.xml</file>
>           </customattribute>
>       </updates>
>   </layout>
> </adminhtml>
> ```

1. Add design layout for adminhtml "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customattribute.xml"

> ```
> <layout version="0.1.0">
>   <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
>       <reference name="order_items">
>             <block type="customattribute/prototal"  name="order_item_extra_info" template="customattribute/productdesign.phtml"/>
>       </reference>
>   </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
> </layout>
> ```

1. Add template File "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customattribute/productdesign.phtml". Please do the format of file placing some sample code.

> ```
> <?php 
> $_item = $this->getItem();
> $sku = $_item->getSku();
> echo '<div style="display:none;"  id="id_order_item_'.$_item->getID().'"> <strong>'.$this->helper('sales')->__('Artwork ID').':</strong>'.$_item->getArtworkID().'</div>'; ?>
> <script>
> function codeAddress<?php echo $_item->getID(); ?>() {
>           var html = document.getElementById('id_order_item_<?php echo $_item->getID(); ?>').innerHTML;
>             var elem = document.getElementById('order_item_<?php echo $_item->getID(); ?>').children[0].innerHTML;
>             document.getElementById('order_item_<?php echo $_item->getID(); ?>').children[0].innerHTML  = elem+html;
>         }
> codeAddress<?php echo $_item->getID(); ?>();
> </script>
> ```

1. For getting Item in your template file you need define a block "CustomAttribute/Block/Adminhtml/Prototal.php"

> class NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Prototal extends
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template
>       {
>         public function setItem(Varien_Object $item) {
>             $this->setData('item', $item);
>             return $this;
>         }
>
> ```
>   public function getItem() {
>       return $this->_getData('item');
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Please comment someone found any issue  or problem.

Answer (score 1):

Doing changes in views/blocks is pretty much the same in frontend and adminhtml. You can create a theme/module and make your changes there  instead of in the core files.
Here is an [official guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) to do that.